# Importing rlcompleter causes terminal resize to fail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

Consider the following code.

```
import curses
import rlcompleter

def main(stdscr):
    while 1:
        c = stdscr.get_wch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

When I run this and resize my terminal, the program fails at the `get_wch`, saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "foo.py", line 6, in main
    c = stdscr.get_wch()
_curses.error: no input
```

However, when I remove the line `import rlcompleter`, a `KEY_RESIZE` is correctly returned and everything works fine.

What is going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this out, and you're a victim of http://bugs.python.org/issue2675 which is more a readline + curses problem than a Python issue.

In short, curses behavior changes based on the environmental variables LINES and COLUMNS, which readline sets.

If you add

```
import os

os.unsetenv('LINES')
os.unsetenv('COLUMNS')
```

Somewhere in there, it will remove the conflict and behave as you expect. If you want to be generous, you might want to save / restore =).